# Streaming Video via Autobahn WebSocket

Tags: opencv, websocket, twisted, autobahn

I capture video frame from **OpenCV** VideoCapture.read() and send the frame to a **WebSocket** server (**Twisted** with **Autobahn** WebSocket API), I also use the Twisted IPushProducer interface to stream data to the WebSocket and eventually it cleans up the camera when sending back to client.

Here is my code.

**server.py**

```
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
import numpy as np
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import  WebSocketServerProtocol, \
                                    WebSocketServerFactory, \
                                    listenWS
from VideoStreamClient import BATH_SIZE

class VideoStreamServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):
    def onConnect(self,request):
        print("Client connecting: {0}".format(request.peer))

    def onOpen(self):
        print("WebSocket connection open.")

    def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
        print("WebSocket connection closed: {0}".format(reason))

    def onMessageBegin(self, isBinary):
        WebSocketServerProtocol.onMessageBegin(self, isBinary)

    def onMessageFrameBegin(self, length):
        WebSocketServerProtocol.onMessageFrameBegin(self, length)
        self.received = 0
        self.next = BATCH_SIZE

    def onMessageFrameData(self, payload):
        self.received += len(payload)
        if self.received >= self.next:
            self.sendMessageFrameData(payload,isBinary=True)
            self.received = 0;

    def onMessageFrameEnd(self):
        pass

    def onMessageEnd(self):
        pass

class VideoStreamServerFactory(WebSocketServerFactory):
    protocol = VideoStreamServerProtocol

    def __init__(self):
        WebSocketServerFactory.__init__(self,"ws://localhost:9000", debug = False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   import sys
   from twisted.python import log
   from twisted.internet import reactor

   log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

   factory = VideoStreamServerFactory()
   listenWS(factory)
   reactor.run()
```

**client.py**

```
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketClientFactory, \
                                   WebSocketClientProtocol, \
                                   connectWS

from zope.interface import implementer
from twisted.internet import reactor, interfaces

import cv2
import numpy as np

FRAME_SIZE = 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
BATCH_SIZE = 1 * 2**20

@implementer(interfaces.IPushProducer)
class VideoStreamProducer:
    def __init__(self,proto):
        self.proto = proto
        self.started = False
        self.paused = False

    def pauseProducing(self):
        self.paused = True

    def resumeProducing(self):
        self.paused = False
        if not self.started:
            self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
            self.cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
            self.cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

            self.proto.beginMessage(isBinary=True)
            self.proto.beginMessageFrame(FRAME_SIZE)
            self.started = True
        while not self.paused:
            isSuccess, frame = self.cap.read()
            _, data = cv2.imencode(".jpg",frame,encode_param)
            if isSuccess:
                if self.proto.sendMessageFrameData(data)<=0:
                    self.proto.beginMessageFrame(FRAME_SIZE)

    def stopProducing(self):
        self.cap.release()

class VideoStreamClientProtocol(WebSocketClientProtocol):
    def onConnect(self,response):
        pass

    def onOpen(self):
        producer = VideoStreamProducer(self)
        self.registerProducer(producer, True)
        producer.resumeProducing()

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        print(len(payload))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    factory = WebSocketClientFactory("ws://localhost:9000")
    factory.protocol = VideoStreamClientProtocol
    connectWS(factory)
    reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an infinite loop that prevents any event-handling from happening once it begins:

```
while not self.paused:
    isSuccess, frame = self.cap.read()
    _, data = cv2.imencode(".jpg",frame,encode_param)
    if isSuccess:
        if self.proto.sendMessageFrameData(data)<=0:
            self.proto.beginMessageFrame(FRAME_SIZE)
```

Remember that Twisted uses a single-threaded cooperative multitasking approach to concurrency.  This loop ties up the (single) reactor thread and does not cooperate with other tasks.

If you want to run some code repeatedly, take a look at `twisted.internet.task.LoopingCall` or `twisted.internet.task.cooperate`.

Comment: Hi, I'd remove the WHILE condition since I'm using IPushProducer. But still loses the camera.

Comment: I don't know what "loses the camera" means.

Comment: The camera stops feeding frame and cleans up. May be this because the blocking UI thread. I'll try the LoopingCall and get back if its works.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've used threads.deferToThread, but still the streaming is not real-time. I'd put my source in https://github.com/dakilasoft/twistedcv and also include a live demo.